# Why isn't my question showing up in active questions when I edit it?

Tags: discussion, support

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723674/is-incompleteness-eliminated-when-construed-within-this-adaptation-to-the-sound

Comment: Probably because it was closed, and now deleted.  The first edit, and only the first edit, of a closed question will send it to a review queue for re-evaluation, but it doesn't "bump" a question to top of the "active questions".

Comment: @amWhy It was not deleted when I asked this question a few seconds ago. Why was it not showing up in active questions then?

Comment: Editing a closed question, as I just explained, if it is the first edit, will send the question to a review queue, but since it was closed when you edited the post, the edit will not bump it to the top of the active questions page.

Comment: @amWhy I still don't quite understand your answer. On other SE groups editing a closed question seems to always put it on top of the active questions. Why did that not happen for my question?

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, but if so, I have no clue why your post did not end up on top of the active questions.  But you should **only ever edit a question to improve it**, not to bring it to the top of the active questions.

Comment: @amWhy If I edit it to improve it and no one sees my improvements then the improvements cannot possibly help. My question was a valid philosophy of the foundation of mathematics question yet no one bothered to look at it closing enough to see this before voting it down.

Comment: The first edit after a post is closed sends it to the reopen review queue, where users with sufficient rep can review the post, after editing, and decide whether to reopen it or not.  So the first edit is the most crucial, because subsequent edits will not send it to the review queue.

Comment: Probably you should clarify what you mean by saying *among active questions* - to make sure that users answering this question look at the same place as you do. Do you mean [active tab on the questions page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=active)? (Also you should make sure that you're looking at the active questions and not at newest questions.)

Answer (score 5):

It is hard to reconstruct what exactly happened but questions with low score are not shown on the front-page.

This  seems a plausible explanation.

Comment: My closed posts in another forum always show up at the top of the active list when I make my best effort to improve them.

Comment: Where they also with such a low score, also there may be a difference between the frontpage and the question-tab.

Comment: They were -4. This one was voted to deletion without comment. It is an easily verifiable fact that the current definition of incompleteness has some serious problems.  A theory T is incomplete if and only if there is some sentence φ such that T⊬φ and T⊬¬φ. This defines every formal system capable of representing self contradiction as incomplete.

Comment: Indeed -4 is the threshold, thus that explains it. Please stop commenting about the rest.

Answer (score 3):

As an experiment, I have just edited a question which has a low score, to check whether it appears among the recently active questions. It was shown there. (It took about a minute after the edit until it appeared there.)

Are you sure that you were looking [at the active tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Active)?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]